# How is a Spring integration Content Enricher implemented using Java only (JavaConfig)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-java-config

I'm trying to find the best Java only way to configure

```
org.springframework.integration.transformer.ContentEnricher
```

It is part of the Message Transformation family, but does not implement Transformer (like HeaderEnricher does), but I've found that this still works:

```
@Bean
@Transformer(inputChannel="requestChannel", outputChannel="replyChannel")
public ContentEnricher contentEnricher() {
    ContentEnricher contentEnricher = new ContentEnricher();
    Map<String, Expression> propertyExpressions = new HashMap<String, Expression>();
    propertyExpressions.put("description", new SpelExpressionParser().parseExpression("'enriching description with static string'"));
    contentEnricher.setPropertyExpressions(propertyExpressions );
    return contentEnricher;
}
```

Is this the best way or are there other better options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's correct config and it works just because `ContentEnricher` is a `MessageHandler` implementation with appropriate `handleMessage(Message<?> message)` method to be accepted from the `MethodInvokingTransformer`.

Another your thought is wrong. The `ContentEnricher` isn't a part of `Transformation family`.

It is exactly some **black box** to extract additional data from an external system and add it to the request message.

See more information here: http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/DataEnricher.html

So, `@ServiceActivator` is better for the `ContentEnricher` case.

In addition, please, pay attention to the [Spring Integration Java DSL](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl) project. It has the `.enrich()` notation.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that the Java Config is correct.My comment that it was part of Transformation was purely driven from Spring docs, which has it as a sub heading of Message Transformation.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that the Java Config is correct..this gives comfort. I'm conflicted on the topic of whether it is a Transformer or not. The Spring Integration docs has the Content Enricher as a sub-heading of Message Transformation, as does [DataEnricher](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/DataEnricher.html) while it also mentions "Use a specialized transformer, a Content Enricher...". I see it does have an internal Gateway so I can also understand why it could be viewed as a '@ServiceActivator' type component also. I will look at the DSL also, thanks.

Comment: Good. Since my position is a bit different and as we see with you it is a bit confusing us, I'll revise those docs in the future. Meanwhile it is good tone to accept answer to mark the question as closed.